# WxPython upgrading 2.8 to 2.9 GUI issue

Tags: python, wxpython

Python 2.7

We are attempting to upgrade from Wx 2.8 to 2.9. We've run into an issue where old code no longer behaves the same in the new version. I have prepared a small example to demonstrate the issue. I believe the problem is stemming from a few lines of code in one of our panels:

```
self.SetSize((-1, 55))
self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize())
self.SetMaxSize(self.GetSize())
```

Perhaps someone has run into this issue and found a different way of achieving the above results? When calling GetSize, the width returns as 20 pixels on the new version of Wx.

**WxPython 2.8.12.1**

[image]

**WxPython 2.9.5.0**

[image]
.

**Here is a sample program that behaves as I've described:**

```
import wx

class OperatorPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        self.__operatorCombo = OperatorCombo(self)

        borderBox = wx.StaticBox(self, -1, "Operator")
        hbox = wx.StaticBoxSizer(borderBox, wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox.Add(self.__operatorCombo, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=5)
        self.SetSizer(hbox)
        self.SetSize((-1, 55))
        self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize())
        self.SetMaxSize(self.GetSize())

class OperatorCombo(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.__comboBox = wx.ComboBox(self, style=wx.CB_READONLY)
        self.__btnAdd = wx.Button(self, label='...', size=(20, -1))
        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hsizer.Add(self.__comboBox, 5, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hsizer.Add(self.__btnAdd, 1)
        self.SetSizer(hsizer)

class TestApp(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, style=wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE | wx.RESIZE_BORDER)

        self.SetSize((350, 300))

        self.__panTop = wx.Panel(self)
        self.__panBottom = wx.Panel(self)

        self.__panOperator1 = OperatorPanel(self.__panTop)
        self.__panOperator2 = OperatorPanel(self.__panTop)

        self.__btnTest = wx.Button(self.__panBottom, -1, "Test", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0)
        testSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        testSizer.Add(self.__btnTest, 0, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        self.__panBottom.SetSizer(testSizer)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        hbox.Add(self.__panOperator1, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        hbox.AddSpacer(5)
        hbox.Add(self.__panOperator2, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND)
        vbox.Add(hbox, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.__panTop.SetSizer(vbox)

        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vsizer.Add(self.__panTop, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=3)
        vsizer.AddSpacer(5)
        vsizer.Add(self.__panBottom, 1, flag=wx.EXPAND | wx.LEFT | wx.RIGHT, border=3)
        # Add more stuff here

        self.SetSizer(vsizer)

app = wx.App()
dlg = TestApp(None)
dlg.ShowModal()
dlg.Destroy()
```

If those three lines are removed, it behaves normally, though the controls are too big vertically.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the StaticBoxSizer, for some reason it doesn't have/get the correct size.

A workaround I found is replacing the three lines with the following:

```
    self.SetSize((-1, 55))
    self.Layout()

    wx.CallAfter(self.mySetSize)

def myPrint(self):
    print('myPrint')
    print(self.GetSize())

def mySetSize(self):
    print('myGetSize')
    self.myPrint()
    self.SetMinSize(self.GetSize())
    self.SetMaxSize(self.GetSize())
```

The print stuff is obviously just for debugging.

BTW, why are you not going up to 3.0.2, or maybe even to wxPython-Phoenix?

2.9.5 will not get any fixes and 3.0.2 has a few corrections which never made it into 2.9.5.

Comment: Hmm, well for our purposes, setting a variable for max / min size and calling that instead of GetSize will work fine. We only updated to fix a blocker-bug fixed in 2.9.5. Going further would require too much migration time. The plan is to phase out python.